# WPF DataBinding specifying array index in Binding not working

Tags: wpf, arrays, data-binding, indexing

I am facing a problem with DataBinding in WPF::::

The below code is working:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ProcessStepBlock.ProcessStep[2].ProcessDescription}"></TextBox>
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ProcessStepBlock.SelectedIndex}" ></TextBox>
```

The below code is not working:It gives me a binding error **BindingExpression path error: '[ ]' property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollectionEx`1'**

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ProcessStepBlock.ProcessStep[ProcessStepBlock.SelectedIndex].ProcessDescription}"></TextBox>
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ProcessStepBlock.SelectedIndex}" ></TextBox>
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XAML parser can't resolve properties to provide values inside a PropertyPath. To get what you're looking for use a MultiBinding that takes both the ProcessStep collection and the SelectedIndex property and create an IMultiValueConverter that produces the ProcessDescription by doing the indexing in code.

Comment: Thanks its working superb!! Now I realise how MultiBindings play a very important role in databinding.